In a set of sets, is the empty set an element, a subset or both?
Basically I'm asking if there are "different" empty sets in between different set structures.
The question came about when solving a linear algebra problem and seeing that $span(\emptyset)={0}$.
But if I define a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ where $A$ is a set of sets of vectors in some vector space $V$, and $B$ is the $span$ of each set $a\in A$, then the confusion comes from the following:
If $\emptyset$ is taken as an element of $A$ ($\emptyset\in A$), then $f(\emptyset)=\{0\}$,
but if $\emptyset$ is taken as a subset of $A$ ($\emptyset\subseteq A$), then $f(\emptyset)$ (i.e. the set images of the subset $\emptyset\subseteq A$) is defined as $f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ (is it not?)
Would love any clarification on the subject.
Edit: Fixed what @jjagmath mentioned, just for clarification.

This is just a question of notation. If you write $f_$ for the action of $f$ on sets instead of reusing $f$, then you have $f(\emptyset) = 0$ and $f_(\emptyset) = \emptyset$.

There is only one $\emptyset$. However, there are two functions here: the function $f:A\to B$, $f(x)=\operatorname{span}(x)$ and the function $f_:\mathcal P(A)\to \mathcal P(B)$, $f_(x)={y\in B,:, \exists u\in x, f(u)=y}$. It's common to use (for a generic $f$, but usually not for $f=\operatorname{span}$) the notation $f$ for $f_$ as well. This is overload of notation is never meant to imply that there is a function $g:A\cup\mathcal P(A)\to B\cup\mathcal P(B)$ such that $\left.g\right\rvert_A=f$ and $\left.g\right\rvert_{\mathcal P(A)}=f_$.

In a set $S$ that contains the empty set, the empty set is both an element of $S$ and a subset of $S$.

Actually $\text{span}(\emptyset) \ne 0$. $\text{span}(\emptyset) = {0}$.

Thanks for all the answers! I think I got it now.

Given any sets $A$ and $B$, a subset $S$ of $A,$ and a function $f:A\to B,$ the set image of $S$ under $f$ is defined as $$f[S]:=\bigl\{b\in B\mid\exists a\in S\bigl(f(a)=b\bigr)\bigr\}.$$
In the case $S=\emptyset$ (vacuously a subset of $A$), we have by this definition that $f[\emptyset]=\emptyset.$ However, in general, $f(\emptyset)$ need not even be defined (and can't be, if $\emptyset\notin A$). This is because we're dealing with a different function, a function $g$ on $\mathcal{P}(A)$ defined by $g(S)=f[S].$
Though closely related, $g(\cdot)$ is not the same function as $f(\cdot).$ Indeed, they cannot be equal, as the domain of the former is the power set of the latter's domain, so it follows by Cantor's Theorem that they have different domains.
Unfortunately, many sources (likely including the one that got you familiarized with notation) would instead use parentheses rather than square brackets (or some other notation distinct from parentheses) when denoting the set image $f[S]$. This can lead to genuine theoretical confusion, as you've discovered! However, in some contexts, one might argue that only one interpretation of $f(\cdot)$ will be coming up, allowing one to avoid any concerns of ambiguity.

Amazing! Thank you very much. I think in your definition of $f[S]$ you put $A$ where $S$ should be, but I got it either way and appreciate the answer and the thought put behind it.

Right you are! I'll fix it presently. Glad I could help!

Oof. I just fixed a much migger mistake. Worth taking another look now.

There are not different empty sets; there is only one empty set in set theory. It's just that the context in which you use the empty set will determine what happens when a function is applied to it.
If you take your function and apply it to the element $\emptyset$, it evaluates f on this specific element.
However, let's say that you take your function and apply it to $\emptyset$, considering $\emptyset$ as a subset of A. Because the empty subset $\emptyset$ has no elements, applying f to every element of $\emptyset$ results in nothing...since there are no elements to apply f to.
So while the empty set itself is the same object, it has a different role based on what structures and functions you are considering. As an element, it has a specific image under f, since it's just $\{\emptyset\}$. But as a subset, it's basically a collection of nothing, so it "maps" to an empty collection of nothing.

As mentioned in a comment, there are really two different functions in the question, both called $f$. That is the source of the confusion.
